# @types/lodash leads to compilation errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, compiler-errors, lodash

In a command line Node.js app, trying to compile `npx ts ...` a TypeScript file after installing `lodash` and `@types/lodash`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

leads to multitudinous errors:

```
Build failed:
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2:16 - error TS2649: Cannot augment module '_' with value exports because it resolves to a non-module entity.

2 declare module "../index" {
                 ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:417:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Dictionary'.

417         at<T>(object:  Dictionary<T> | NumericDictionary<T> | null | undefined, ...props: PropertyPath[]): T[];
                           ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:417:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NumericDictionary'.

417         at<T>(object:  Dictionary<T> | NumericDictionary<T> | null | undefined, ...props: PropertyPath[]): T[];
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:417:91 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PropertyPath'.

417         at<T>(object:  Dictionary<T> | NumericDictionary<T> | null | undefined, ...props: PropertyPath[]): T[];
                                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:421:76 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Many'.

421         at<T extends object>(object: T | null | undefined, ...props: Array<Many<keyof T>>): Array<T[keyof T]>;
                                                                               ~~~~
...
```

Is this because of non-compatible versions of `@types/lodash` and `lodash`?

Which versions of `@types/lodash` and `lodash` you recommend to install? Or how otherwise to solve these errors?

Here is the code:

```js
import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

function runThread() {
  const worker = new Worker('./worker.js', { workerData: {} });

  worker.on('message', (response) => {
    console.log(`Response from worker:`, response);
  });

  worker.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(`Error in worker:`, error);
  });

  worker.on('exit', (code) => {
    if (code !== 0) {
      console.error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`);
    }
  });
}

console.log("Starting threads...")
runThread();
runThread();
```

Comment: Can you show the TS code you try to compile?

Comment: @LinDu Oh, much sorry, I didn't commit that old version of the code to my Git repo, and it was lost.

Comment: @LinDu I've found the code (see the edited question).